# How to clear cache for a particular webpage in a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

I have a Rails application running and there are several webpages and I am using default Rails caching. All the cache is stored in tmp/cache directory. I want to delete cache only for particular webpage and I want to do it on terminal something like rm -rf

Answer (score 0):

`rake tmp:cache:clear` is your command.

You can also clear cache with `Rails.cache.clear`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to clearing a [fragment cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching), one common pattern is to append a version string so that when you change the HTML of a view template, the cache for that template is busted. For example instead of:

```
<% cache do %>
  All available products:
  <% Product.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Do the following:

```
<% cache 'v1' do %>
  All available products:
  <% Product.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That way when you want to change the HTML inside of the cache block, you just change the string to 'v2'.